# Does Magento 2's UpgradeSchema Pattern Handle non-contiguous Version Jumps

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade, installation, setup-upgrade

Magento 2 replaced Magento 1's Setup Upgrade scripts with a `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

When a module's installed, this command looks for a `InstallSchema` and `InstallData` class in a module's `Setup` folder, and runs both class's `install` method.

When a module is upgraded, this command looks for an `UpgradeSchema` and `UpgradeData` class in a module's `Setup` folder, and runs these class's `upgrade` method.  Unlike Magento 1, there is no longer any built-in logic to run through a set of scripts named with version numbers.

The pattern used by Magento 2's core in Upgrade scripts looks like this

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
        //... upgrade scripts here ...
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.2') < 0) {
        //... upgrade scripts here ...            
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.3') < 0) {
        //... upgrade scripts here ...        
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.4') < 0) {
        //... upgrade scripts here ...        
    }
}
```

i.e. The Upgrade classes need to include programatic logic for version checks.

Looking over how Magento's coded these in the core though -- it's not clear how this system works.  Is `$context->getVersion()` the version of am module the user is upgrading from?  Or to?  If you're jumping module versions (from say, `2.0.2` to `2.0.5`) does `setup:upgrade` call this `upgrade` once, or does it run through the scripts multiple times (one for the `2.0.3` upgrade, again for `2.0.4` upgrade, and again for `2.0.5` ?

This doesn't (seem to be) documented on the dev docs site -- and setup code is pretty tricky to test by trial and error. Does anyone know how these work, and if Magento's implementation is "non-contiguous version upgrade" safe?  If you're tempted to answer *of course* to the later without testing -- welcome newcomer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the upgrade steps as I understand them:

- For all active modules `$ bin/magento setup:upgrade` checks the *configured* (`module.xml` file) version versus the *database* (**setup_module** table) schema+data values [1]
- Differences between configured version and database version trigger execution of `UpgradeSchema->upgrade()` and then `UpgradeData->upgrade()` for each module one time each [2]
- `$context->getVersion()` returns the respective database value for that module from the **setup_module** table, and that is used in the conditional state

[1] As with Magento 1, the **`setup_module.schema_version`** and **`setup_module.data_version`** values will (should) always be the equal; unequal values indicates a failed upgrade process.

Tangentially, thanks for reminding me to get an answer on why we changed approach. (I think that I have once, but I've forgotten.) I'll also see about getting all of this more thoroughly documented, including...

[2] ...the caveat that each `upgrade()` is only executed once with the corresponding value from the database, which means that the entire upgrade logic is processed *sequentially per module*, which must be considered if a module depends on some other module's schema or data to be at a certain state.